# How do I add or remove an object to an array from another object

Tags: processing

So in my program I have an object called Creatures and I have loaded it in via an array, all fine and dandy. But I want to add a way for the creature to repoduce and thus adding a copy of him to the array, but the problem is that the array is saved in another object. This is my code so far: (I have cut out some unrelated code)
The main part where my code is ran:

```
// Setting creature
Creature[] Creatures = new Creature[20];

void setup() {
  size(1280,720,P2D);

  // Initializing Creatures
  for(int i = 0; i < Creatures.length; i++) {
    Creatures[i] = new Creature(true, "");
  }
}

void draw()
{
  update();

  //TODO: Add more
}

void update() {
  //Updating the creatures
  for(int i = 0; i < Creatures.length; i++) {
    Creatures[i].update();
  }
}
```

And the part with the Creature class:

```
class Creature {
  String race;

  float x;
  float y;

  float r;
  float g;
  float b;

  ExtraUtils EU = new ExtraUtils();

  Creature(boolean genned, String pRace) {
    x = (float)Math.random() * width;
    y = (float)Math.random() * height;

    r = (float)Math.random() * 255;
    g = (float)Math.random() * 255;
    b = (float)Math.random() * 255;

    if(genned)
    {
      race = EU.RandomString(round((float)Math.random()*5+3));
    } else {
      race = pRace;
    }
  }

  void update() {
    strokeWeight(0);
    fill(r,g,b);

    x+=(float)Math.random()*3 - 1.5;
    y+=(float)Math.random()*3 - 1.5;

    rect(x,y,8,8);

    text(race,x,y);
  }
}
```

If anyone would like to help me with this (with this i mean add a new creature to the Creatures array from the Creature class) I would be very very happy!

Comment: To confirm, you want to use your `Creature` class to add a `creature` object to the array you created in another file or class? If that is the case, you could make your array `static`.

Comment: yeah, so the Creature can repoduce and make clones of it's self

Comment: Is your problem the actual code to clone the object, or is your problem just trying to access the `creatures` array from your first snippet in the `Creature` class?

Comment: I'd like to access the Creatures array from the Creature class, I think I know how to clone it from there.

Comment: Is my updated answer any help?

Comment: I was wondering if you were able to solve your problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an Array, use an ArrayList. It is more dynamic.

So, inside creatures we will have:

```
class Creature {

    ArrayList<Creature> creatures = new ArrayList<Creature>();

    //You can access the above ArrayList and add to it at any point in this class with creature.add().

    //The rest of your class below.

}
```

Since you defined the ArrayList in the `Creature` class, to add to it, just reference that object of the class.

```
Creature creature = new Creature(); //Whatever constructor paramaters you want to use.
creature.creatures.add();           //This is where you will add your object.
```

**Update**

I wanted to take the time to explain fully the final implementation.

You have created the `ArrayList` in the `Creature` class, so that means you do not need the `Creature[]` array in your sketch. So, remove that, and the for loop you have in `Setup()`.

When you want to update the `Creature` objects in the `creatures` ArrayList, inside your sketch (not the `Creature` class), you will just do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < creature.creatures.size; i++) {
    creature.creatures.get(i).update();
}
```

In conclusion, here are the final code snippets that should work for your implementation:

**1.) No change needed in class Creature.** The `Creature` class has no changes other than adding the `ArrayList` I mentioned earlier.

**2.) Your sketch:**

```
// Setting Creature Object
Creature creature = new Creature(); //Whatever paramaters you want to add for the constructor.

void setup() {
    size(1280,720,P2D);

    // Initalizing Creature objects inside list.
    for(int i = 0; i < QUANTITY_TO_ADD; i++) {
        creatures.creature.add(new Creature(true, ""));
    }
}

void draw()
{
    update();

    //TODO: Add more
}

void update() {
   //Updating the creatures
  for(int i = 0; i < creature.creatures.size(); i++) {
      creature.creatures.get(i).update();
  }
}
```

**Note:** `QUANTITY_TO_ADD` is merely a place holder.

**Conclusion:**

Now, your implementation is dynamic, and you only have one copy of the ArrayList stored, so you don't have to worry about saving updates between classes. The ArrayList is initialized in `Creature` and you can use the `add()` and `get()` methods to modify or get any elements in wherever, so long as you use the object of the `Creature` class to access it.

Comment: What would I have to do in the main file though to keep the creatures in there, and by copying over your code above i get an error: Unexpected Token: >

Comment: @A.Moulding You accepted the answer, so does it work now or is there any way I can still help you?

Answer (score -1):

Passing creature array pointer to a member function of Creature should help, right?

Comment: I'm new to programming so I don't completely know what you mean but I think you mean that I should get a function in creature and pass the creature array through that, if I understand it correctly I don't think that would work as I wouldn't be able to edit it and add more creatures

Comment: @A.Moulding what language are you using?

Comment: Wait I think I know what you mean. And this will actually help, I can keep loading that function (like update();) and then when a variable inside of the creature says to clone himself he can return the array, modified to add a new creature

Comment: I'm using Processing with Java.

Comment: I'm still struggling though how would I make a function that allows the passing over of a Creature[] (So a creature array) because it gives me an error when I try: void reproduce(Creature[]) {
    
  } The error says "...VariableDeclaratold"

Comment: it is not my cup of tea then, but if you want my technique pass to function what array you have, if you can modify, modify it and return it back or else create new array, copy contents of passed array, add new creature and return the new array (if possible delete the old array)

Comment: or you ask the creature member function to create a new creature and return it. After getting the new creature, you can add it to the array from outside the class